# juju on local server + wrapping my own application server custom built wtih charm

Tags: ubuntu, automated-install, continuous-integration, juju

I'm interested in juju before starting with it i would like to ask a few questions.

1. Can juju be only be used with ubuntu? is it possible to use it with CentOS?
2. I have my own application server which i wrote, can i wrap it in a charm and deploy it on my local juju cloud? (I do not publish ofcourse my charm to the openstack because its a propriety server code, if yes can someone direct me maybe to a link of how i can achieve such a thing?) my server is built with java.
3. Is ubuntu server + full capabilities of juju always be free of charge?
4. Which technologies would you recommend me to write my app server installer (i'm going to go for continuous deployment on my own cloud rolled, perhaps with juju).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find inline answers along with.

1. Juju is primarily supported for Ubuntu but code is open so one can easily get it working on another distribution.
2. https://askubuntu.com/questions/65359/how-do-i-configure-juju-for-local-usage  This might help.
3. Yes
4. You can write charms in any programming language you are comfortable with. http://juju.ubuntu.com has all the details you need.